# How to test assignment of a Proc via Rspec?

Tags: ruby, testing, lambda, rspec

I'm using the `DataMapper` gem.

I have some code that dynamically creates tables based on certain rules. So I have a line of code like this:

```
def set_table_name(table_name:)
  adapter = DataMapper.repository(:default).adapter
  adapter.resource_naming_convention = lambda { |_| table_name }
end
```

This comes straight from their documentation: http://www.rubydoc.info/github/datamapper/dm-core/DataMapper/NamingConventions

This works just fine, but I want to write a spec to know that it's setting the naming convention correctly. If it wasn't a lambda but just setting the value, then I'd probably do:

```
# assume 'adapter' is already set in the test, either as a mock or whatever
expect(adapter).to receive(:resource_naming_convention=).with("some_value")
something.set_table_name(table_name: "some_value")
```

Since DataMapper is an external dependency, I don't know what side-effects or requirements the setter has, so I just want to verify that it's getting called correctly.

However, since it's being called with a lambda, I'm not sure how to do this. I can do this:

```
# assume 'adapter' is already set in the test, either as a mock or whatever
expect(adapter).to receive(:resource_naming_convention=).with(kind_of(Proc))
something.set_table_name(table_name: "some_value")
```

But I'd really like to validate that "some_value" is the execution value of the Proc.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to extract the lamda to a function and stub it out:

```
def set_table_name(table_name:)
  adapter = DataMapper.repository(:default).adapter
  adapter.resource_naming_convention = naming_convention_lambda
end

def naming_convention_lambda
  lambda { |_| table_name }
end

# in tests ...

fn = lambda { |_| table_name }
expect(something).to(
  receive(:naming_convention_lambda).and_return(fn)
)
expect(adapter).to(
  receive(:resource_naming_convention=).with(fn)
)
```

You could test the lambda separately if you wanted.

Also, you could change the lambda to a proc and get rid of the `|_|` bit since it doesn't require the correct argument length.